# Asking device music playback from inside XNA (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, media, playlist

I can access the media library just fine but it means I have to develop my own interface to get a player to select a music track to play or a play list or something.

Is it possible to display the OS's native music browser from inside the game then when the user finishes using it (i.e. selecting their track to play or play list) jump back into the game?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK currently contains no built in way to display a list of music on the device from within your own application.

Unfortunately, you'll have to implement your own solution.

Comment: Ah damn that sucks :( Ah well, I shouldn't be so lazy.

Comment: @meds consider it an opportunity to create something specifically tailored to be part of your application rather than just a standard control